# How do I use the Python API pygoogle?

Tags: python, linux

I just found out about this Python API called pygoogle. I downloaded it but now I don't know what to do or how to use it. Does anyone have experience with this so you could help me?

Comment: I found this, https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/

Comment: well yes.  I read it but it just doesn't say what i have to do. When i try from pygoogle import pygoogle
g = pygoogle('quake 3 arena')
g.pages = 5
print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
g.get_urls()

i get error. Sorry for being a noob. Until now i've programmed in java so python is new to me

Comment: For future reference: Being a noob is not a problem here. Newcomer questions are on equal ground with everyone else's questions. The problem is how broad this question is: If you have tried to use the API, share your code. What errors or undesired behavior do you see? What did you expect? If you don't understand documentation, **exactly** which section or paragraphs don't you understand? You mentioned in a comment on the answer below, that you're getting an error while importing. Why wasn't that in your question? We can't explain all of the documentation to you, so you have to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: The SOAP API is no longer supported by Google.

```
pip install pygoogle-simple
```

to get the supported AJAX version.

Here is some basic information on using pygoogle.  There's also xgoogle which may be of some interest.  It looks like pygoogle has limits to 64 results whereas exgoogle has more.

```
from pygoogle import pygoogle
g = pygoogle('quake 3 arena')
g.pages = 5
print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
g.get_urls()
```

[pygoogle info](https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/)

Comment: you don't understand my question. I tried that but i get an error saying there is no module named python.

Comment: I read where Google no longer supports the SOAP API.  Checkout pygoogle-simple which uses AJAX.  I did get the same type of error with pygoogle.  A module error.

Comment: Tested pygoogle-simple and it works.  I'll be using this!

Comment: For me it still show this error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: pygoogle is no longer supported.  Did you get pygoogle-simple?  https://github.com/PixxxeL/pygoogle-simple has an example that I tested and it does work

Comment: Are you running the code from the Python shell or from a .py file? i.e. python myfile.py